# Running access for Artifactory

Tags: war, artifactory

New to Artifactory so please bear with me.

Trying (and failing) to create new access token.
The GUI in Artifactory has nothing for this but points to a users guide (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Access+Tokens) which talks about managing access tokens through a WAR file.
Here is the blurb:

```
Access Service

From Artifactory version 5.4, access tokens are managed under a new service 
called Access which is implemented in a separate WAR file, access.war. This 
change has no impact on how access tokens are used, however, the Artifactory 
installation file structure now also includes the added WAR file under the 
$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/webapps folder. Artifactory communicates with the Access 
service over HTTP and assumes it is running in the same Tomcat using the 
context path of "access".
```

OK, great.  So how do I access this thing?
I also don't know much about web apps/servers.  Prior to today, I thought WAR was a fight between nations :-)

My Artifactory server proc is running, and I can confirm that the access war file (apparently a jar file of sorts) is in the webapps dir.
I am able to get a artifactory via "http://myserver:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/home".

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I believe the interface to manage access tokens is not provided through a gui.  Rather, you have to use REST and curl commands.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions:

> It is up to the Artifactory administrator to make sure that all participating instances are equipped with the same key pair.

That means you need to have access to the server (where Artifactory is installed).
On that server, the folder where Artifactory is installed is reference ARTIFACTORY_HOME.
That is what is used in the next doc extract:

> 1. Start up the first Artifactory instance (or cluster node for an HA installation) that will be in your circle of trust. A private key and root certificate are generated and stored under **`$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/access/etc/keys`**.
> 2. Copy the private key and root certificate files to a location on your file system that is accessible by all other instances/nodes that are in your circle of trust.
> 3. Before bootstrapping, for each of the other instances/nodes, create the `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/access/etc` folder and create a properties file in it called `access.bootstrap.config` with the following contents:

```
    key=/path/to/private.key
    crt=/path/to/root.crt
```

> 4. When each instance/node starts up, if the `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/access/etc/access.bootstrap.config` file exists, then the private key and root certificate are copied from the specified location into the server's home directory under `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/access/etc/keys`.

Comment: Thanks VonC for the help.

Comment: Thanks VonC for the help.  But the problem I am having is to get Access to run locally, on the same host that Artifactory is running.  I thought that it would have just been something under the admin menu. Instead it talked about using the access WAR.  Don't know how to do that.

I feel that I'm missing something conceptually here.  

Again, thanks for the response.

Comment: "I am having is to get Access to run locally, on the same host that Artifactory is running.": you don't have to do anything: Artifactory will use access.war when needed.I do see the webapp access (from `D:\artifactory\pro\artifactory-pro-5.4.6\webapps\access.war`) deployed in my  Tomcat Artifactory instance: `D:\artifactory\pro\artifactory-pro-5.4.6\tomcat\webapps`. I didn't have to do anything for that.

Comment: I created token (e.g. curl uadmin:adminpw -XPOST "http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/security/token" -d "username=myuname").  

Msg contains an "access token" which is a very long string, but in the gui, the "token id" created is like xxxxx500-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.   

I try to ping using...
curl -umyuname:xxxxx500-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/system/ping 

Fails with a 401 (bad credentials).
I replace the token with the very long version, same result
I replace again with the hardcoded pw and that works.

How to get Token to work ?

Comment: @daveg try instead to use the token as username, with an empty password: `curl -uxxxx500-... myserver...`